# Laravel Auth::id()

Tags: php, laravel-5

How does Laravel `Auth::id()` work ?

```
$widget = Widget::create([ 'name' => $request->name,
                           'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
                           'slug' =>$slug]);
```

Comment: This was the very first result for "laravel auth::id()" in Google. Did you even try looking yourself? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the id of currently authorized user.

Comment: Thank you @Otkelbay Akberdi .